# What is a "--wait" file

Tags: git, git-merge

I recently had branches that looked like:

```
   ----------------B
  /    -------A
 /    /
-------master-----
```

I merged A into master, no problem via a pull request.
The pull request automatically performs the merge into master for me.

I then wanted to bring those changes into B, so I

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout B
git merge master
```

and it opens notepad++ for me with a merge message file and a wait file. I typed a message into the merge message file and left the `--wait` file empty. When I closed notepad++ it did the merge. There `--wait` file is now in my source tree and git thinks it is a modified file.

What is it? do I delete it?

Comment: Looks like git tried to pass a flag (`--wait`)  to np++ but np++ doesn't know this flag and just assumed it was a filename.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `--wait` file. Some editors need to be told to wait around until the commit message is written back (others wait automatically). Obviously whoever configured your Git thought this was true for the `notepad++` editor, but `notepad++` disagrees and just creates a file named `--wait` instead. So it's a user configuration error. (Note: I know nothing about notepad++, but this is a general problem that applies to many editors.)

Comment: Any ideas on where I look for the bad configuration piece?

Comment: Ah! found it in my .gitconfig. Anyone want to make that an official answer, so I can mark it? might help someone else with the same configuration problem down the road.